# Using anchor tag to load a javascript in the browser address bar

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a harlem shake effect.(an effect in which various things,imgs on page start moving back and fro)[Demo of harlem shake](http://blog.moovweb.com/2013/02/happy-valentines-day-internet-behold-the-harlem-shake-bookmarklet)

When we paste a certain code starting with `javascript:(function(){function c(){var e.......long code..` in the address bar of the browser,the effect starts..(the effect is that elements on the page start dancing).

Is there any way to put that code in the browser when a user clicks somewhere on a webpage.
here's what i tried,but in vain

The  code(sorry,its a little long) http://pastebin.com/BGzXve64

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){function c(){var e.......long code">click me</a>
```

[Js fiddle,not working coz the main code has internal html tags](http://jsfiddle.net/TtBjr/1/)

Another thing perhaps is

```
<a onclick="javascript:(function(){function c(){var e.......long code">Click me for harlem shake</a>
```

[Js fiddle,not working coz the main code has internal html tags](http://jsfiddle.net/6jdNk/)

Is there a common simpler(or working) way to put such urls in browser address bar onclick?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you need to grab the javascript code inside the bookmarklet and use it in a different way. See fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/EaYRQ/2/

For your anchor or w/e element you use, just add the `onclick=harlem()`

```
<a href="#" onclick="harlem()">Click Me</a>
```

And javascript. Just copy the javascript section of the jsfiddle

```
window.harlem = function () { ... }
```